# Damping of not harmonic waves

Tags: waves, frequency

You [pluck](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/31101/38172) a (guitar) string so that you create a wave with [harmonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic) frequency and a wave with not-harmonic frequency.

Which one will be heard longer? Why?

Or ask it differently: Is the wave with not-harmonic frequency damped a lot faster than the harmonic one?

Comment: I assume you mean damped not dumped. Can you say a bit more about what you mean by "not harmonic" frequencies. Do you just mean frequencies that are not integer multiples of the fundamental?

Comment: This question will probably get better results over at music.stackexchange.  Damping of sound in a musical instrument has a lot to do with the type of instrument, the natural resonances of the body (e.g. guitar or violin), and more.  It's not at all a simple problem.

Comment: Yes I mean exactly not integer multiples of the fundamental.

Comment: How will you create that non-harmonic vibration? ""You pluck a guitar.. so that..."" does not give an idea to me how to do that.

Comment: I assume that when you pluck a guitar string you create a set of various waves. And I try to understand why you hear just those "right" ones.

Comment: You can *always* decompose the vibration into a superposition of harmonics. Therefore the question becomes whether or not different harmonics have different damping rates. It depends on what's causing the damping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a typical treatment of an *ideal* (under)damped harmonic oscillator, the damping term is proportional to velocity, but is otherwise assumed to be independent of frequency.

In this case the rate at which the oscillations diminish goes as $\exp (-\gamma t)$, where $\gamma$ is some sort of damping constant.

Of course what must be true is that the amplitude of the anharmonics will presumably be lower than the fundamental and harmonics, so presumably if they all decay at the same rate, the anharmonics drop below the threshold of hearing more quickly than the harmonics.

However the last comment you have made makes me think you want to know the answer to a different question, which is why the harmonics have higher amplitudes to begin with? The answer to this is that if you stimulate the string across a broad range of frequencies, the response of the string is much stronger at frequencies corresponding to the fundamental mode of vibration and its harmonics. This is the basic phenomenon of [resonance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance).

Comment: For anharmonic waves, isn't there additional damping term at the ends of string caused by the fact that the ends are not the nodes of the wave?

Comment: @Peter  I don't think you would interpret it that way. This is the reason that anharmonic waves do not have large amplitudes in the first place. You can excite anharmonic waves by stimulating the string at the corresponding frequency, but its harder to do.

Comment: " why the harmonics have higher amplitudes to begin with? The answer to this is that if you stimulate the string across a broad range of frequencies, the response of the string is much stronger at frequencies corresponding to the fundamental mode of vibration and its harmonics. "

This is quite a circular definition, I think it's the most poorly explained part of the topic always, so it might be useful to elaborate. Most of the time the explanation doesn't go further than "only harmonics fit" or "because they are integer multiples."